# Star Rating component fill all previous stars on hover

Tags: html, css, angular

I am currently making a Star Rating component for our website, I use angular11 (should not matter I think), so far I have the rendering of the 5 stars depending on the current rating value and such, but I struggle to get the styling for the hovering correct.

Basicly for example if I have 2 out of 5 stars and I hover the 4th star the 3th should be filled too.
I struggle to find the correct css to achieve that
Thats what I got so far in CSS

```
.rating-icon-empty { fill: #9e9e9e }
.rating-icon { fill: #7C4DFF; margin-right: 5px; }
.editable .rating-icon-empty:hover { fill: #7C4DFF; cursor: pointer;}
```

My current CSS only fills the star that is hovered but not the previous unfilled stars.

Is there a way to achieve this with pure CSS or do I need to rely on hover listeners for each star?

Comment: It would be useful to have the HTML, with inline SVG, in your question.

Comment: See here: https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh it works very well (I integrated it successfully).

Answer (score 3):

I had your problem before, read these:

#### First Solution:

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body{ margin: 20px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating > input { display: none; } 
.rating > label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating > .half:before { 
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
 float: right; 
}

/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

```html
<h1>Pure CSS Star Rating Widget</h1>
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Source:

- https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh

#### Second Solution:

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.rating {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
}

.rating>span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 1.1em;
}

.rating>span:hover:before,
.rating>span:hover~span:before {
    content: "\2605";
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="rating">
        <span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Source:

- https://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/

if you have any problems let me know.